# Script that rotates a PNG in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, extendscript, jsx, photoshop-script

I have the following Photoshop ExtendScript (.jsx) script which rotates the image canvas, but doesn't rotate the contents:

```
var doc = app.open(...);       // open the .png file

if (doc.width > doc.height) {  // check if this document is landscape
  doc.rotateCanvas(90);        // rotate the canvas to portrait

  // but how to rotate the contents?
}
```

I would like to rotate the entire image, contents included. I've tried also rotating all the document's layers, and art layers, but nothing works.

Comment: I've offered a cash bounty for this question at http://www.code4cheap.com/question/16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... uh... yeah. If you want to rotate a PNG in Photoshop, the above script would be the way to do it. Code not shown here might cause it do something different, preventing the rotate from succeeding :).